# How do I Create Bootstrap Thumbnail Items in DivShot?

Tags: divshot

DivShot is looking really awesome, finding it really useful as I'm a newbie to Bootstrap. One thing i cant see in there is how to create Thumbnail grids (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails). Is there a away of doing this or am i missing something?

Cheers
Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Unfortunly there is no thumbnail possibility in divshot. But divshot has a nice included html editor and u can add the thumbnail syntax there. 
The css is always available via the bootstrap.css

Comment: Thanks Denny, the screenshot you have on there is of the 'Image' element whereas the 'Thumbnail' element can be used for more complex info like a list of e-commerce products etc. hope that makes sense and apologies if I ma missing something within the image element that does this but still cant see how to do this

Comment: Thanks Denny, much appreciated, I thought that might be the case but wanted to check. I can create this code no problem